# In camel how i can update a result set coloumn to a value

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

My select query is

```
sql.selectOrder=select STID,CLLTR from GSI_DEVL.POLLUX_DATA WHERE PROCESSED='FALSE'
```

My Route is

```
<route id="markRowsAsProcessed-Route"  >
         <!--    <from uri="timer://markRowsAsProcessed?delay=5000"/>-->
        <from uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.selectOrder}}?consumer.useIterator=false" />   
        <doTry>
              <to uri="bean:rowProcessController"/>  
            <to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.markRows}}?batch=true"/>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>    
                <exception>java.lang.IllegalStateException</exception>
                <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
                <exception>java.lang.ClassCastException</exception> 
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>    
    </route>
```

My bean is

```
public class RowProcessController {
    List<Map<String, Object>> stationUnMarkedList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> stationMarkedList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String,Object> stationMap = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Handler
    public List<Map<String, Object>> markRowAsProcessed(Exchange exchange)
    {
        stationUnMarkedList = (List<Map<String, Object>>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
        for(Map<String,Object> data: stationMarkedList) {
            System.out.println(data.get("STID"));
            stationMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
            stationMap.put("stationId", ((String)data.get("STID")));
            stationMap.put("callLetter", ((String)data.get("CLLTR")));
            stationMarkedList.add(stationMap);
        }
        return stationMarkedList;
    }
}
```

I want to update the result set processed column to done or some value.

I tried

```
sql.markRows=UPDATE POLLUX_DATA SET PROCESSED='DONE' where stid=:stationId
```

But this does not update any values in the database.  Why not?

Comment: Are you sure that the body has the correct type?
Named variables used in SQL statements must be definied as header or in the body if its a java.util.Map (see [link](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html)).
You could also try to set header **stationId** on the exchange.

Comment: if remove named queries,the same issue persist.if i remove the select statement and try a direct update statement then its working.I think some problems with these combinatins.In camel is there is any restriction to use select and update together.I mean can i process the result set throug a bean and update the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and change the query's named parameter notation to :# instead of just :

sql.markRows=UPDATE POLLUX_DATA SET PROCESSED='DONE' where stid=:#stationId

Comment: Sundar,Stiil its not updating.i was using :#stationId when i was posting this.Wrongly i pasted here as :stationId.

I need to mark the row as processed

Comment: On looking in to your code i think the issue is a typo , you are trying to iterate through a empty list in your bean   , you are reading the body in to a list   stationUnMarkedList but iterating through stationMarkedList , so the body to the update query is a empty list. I would suggest to add logs and also when handling exceptions try to do something about it , do not swallow exceptions.